# R - Object not interpretable as a factor w/ previously working code?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, readxl

So I am facing this error where code that used to work perfectly... suddenly doesn't and I get this error:

> Object not interpretable as a factor

I have a excel file that I'm importing that looks something like this:

```
GENDER  RACE    HEIGHT  WEIGHT  PEF    FEV1  FVC    AGE
0       1       128     26      5.02   1.79  1.94   107.4
0       1       126     24      4.61   1.31  1.31   89.955
0       1       98      13      1.67   0.56  0.56   64.723
0       1       110     21      2.08   1.07  1.12   55.326
0       1       107     17      1.88   0.7   0.84   54.965
0       1       123     28      3.14   .48   1.5    71.195
```

I use `readxl` for this:

```
dataset <- read_excel("PATHTOFILE/FEVWORKPLZ.xlsx")
#then do some processing, etc: 
FEV_df <- data.frame(t(sapply(dataset,c)))
n <- FEV_df$name
FEVDF <- as.data.frame(t(FEV_df[,-1]))
```

Point is, I can print `FEVDF` and see all 8 columns of the dataframe getting printed after the above code. Then comes the part that I don't understand... The exact same line will error... *sometimes* :

[image]

For the first erroring line of `FEVDF[,c(4)]`, I copied the `FEVDF[,c(3)]` and changed the 3 to 4... for the second line, I copied the second half of the working `WEIGHT` line. Why would this make any sort of difference?

So the question is.. **What can be going wrong here?**

I've spent hours trying to understand what could be wrong.. should I change data formats? Is this some kind of configuration issue? I tried clearing objects from the workspace in RStudio but that doesn't help either. I also restarted RStudio.... with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is different than `C`.  Case matters in R.  You get an error when using `C` and you don't when you use `c` because they're different.

Comment: Oh my god.... you are right. Thank you for correcting this idiotic mistake. My laptop font was unfortunately too small that I couldn't see the difference on my screen without zooming.

Comment: Note that in this case you don't even need to make a call to `c`.